# Comando enquanto em código no VisualG

Tags: algoritmo, visualg, portugol

Boa noite pessoal. Tenho esse código feito e preciso fazer o que o exercício está pedindo, mas não estou entendendo e não sei como fazer. A única dica que tenho é que se deve utilizar o comando *enquanto*. A tecla utilizada para fazer um novo pedido (pode ser um, dois, ou mais pedidos) é a tecla "s". Para encerrar o pedido, se utiliza a tecla "n". Alguém tem alguma dica de como o código deve ficar?

Agradeço desde já. Segue o exercício:

*1) Escreva um algoritmo que ao final da exibição na tela da escolha do cliente pergunte se ele gostaria de realizar outro pedido. Se o cliente quiser fazer um novo pedido, deverá pressionar a tecla “s” (sem aspas e em minúsculo). Se não quiser fazer um novo pedido, deverá pressionar a tecla "n" (sem aspas e em minúsculo), assim o pedido será finalizado.*

```
Var
// Seção de Declarações das variáveis 
opcao, quantidade: inteiro
valor: real
Inicio
// Seção de Comandos, procedimento, funções, operadores, etc...

escreval ("   Lanchonete Central   ")
escreval ("   ------------------   ")
escreval (" ***Opções de lanches*** ")
escreval (" [1] - Torrada Simples -> R$ 4,00")
escreval (" [2] - Torrada Completa -> R$ 5,00")
escreval (" [3] - Cachorro Quente Simples -> R$ 5,00")
escreval (" [4] - Cachorro Quente Completo -> R$ 6,00")
escreval (" [5] - Cheeseburger Completo -> R$ 8,00")
escreval ("Digite a opção escolhida")
leia (opcao)
escreval ("Qual a quantidade desejada?")
leia (quantidade)

escolha opcao
caso 1
valor:=quantidade*4
escreval ("O lanche escolhido foi ",quantidade," Torrada Simples(s) e custará R$ ", valor,",00")
caso 2
valor:=quantidade*5
escreval ("O lanche escolhido foi ",quantidade," Torrada Completa(s) e custará R$ ", valor,",00")
caso 3
valor:=quantidade*5
escreval ("O lanche escolhido foi ",quantidade," Cachorro Quente Simples(s) e custará R$ ", valor,",00")
caso 4
valor:=quantidade*6
escreval ("O lanche escolhido foi ",quantidade," Cachorro Quente Completo(s) e custará R$ ", valor,",00"
caso 5
valor:=quantidade*8
escreval ("O lanche escolhido foi ",quantidade," Cheeseburger Completo(s) e custará R$ ", valor,",00")


fimescolha

Fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: declare uma variável como caractere, ex: `continuar: caractere`. Logo após o inicio do programa, coloque na primeira linha `continuar:="s"`na linha abaixo coloque esta instrução: `enquanto continuar <> "n" faca`, e  após o seu `fimescolha` coloque a  instrução: `escreval ("Deseja fazer um novo pedido? ")
escreval (" Digite s = sim ou  n = não")
leia(continuar)`  deverá funcionar! lembre-se de fechar a estrutura enquanto com um `fimenquanto`

Comment: Muito obrigado, Luiz Augusto! Deu certinho!